# Creation of a hierarchically structured report based on a control table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a hierarchy based on a table like this:

| Item | Cat 1 | Cat 2 | Cat 3 | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Apple | Fruit | Store 1 | 100 |
| 002 | Orange | Fruit | Store 1 | 100 |
| 003 | Cucumber | Vegetable | Store 1 | 100 |
| 004 | Tomatoe | Vegetable | Store 1 | 100 |
| 005 | Apple | Fruit | Store 2 | 100 |

The hierarchy in Excel should look like this:

| Category | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| .... Apple | 100 |
| .... Orange | 100 |
| ..[-] Fruit | 200 |
| .... Cucumber | 100 |
| .... Tomatoe | 100 |
| ..[-] Vegetable | 200 |
| [-] Store 1 | 400 |
| .... Apple | 100 |
| ..[-] Fruit | 100 |
| [-] Store 2 | 100 |

For each category there should be a totals row (below) that also groups the corresponding item rows above (with expand/ collapse).

I started with a loop over each row of the control table, that detects when a CAT3/2/1 value has changed and then writes a totals row.
This turned out to be quite messy after a while.

My second attempt was to create three arrays with distinct categories and looping through these arrays.
That took a a long time and seemed inefficient.

Any other ideas?

Not showing any code as I would like to keep it abstract.

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this.

Comment: Thanks Tim! The final report, though, must have a certain format (with blank lines, etc.). That's why I didn't go this route.

Comment: Insufficient information. However, from what little you supply, my suggestion would be using a dictionary and classes to collect and organize your data. Once you have it properly organized, you can output it in whatever format you require.

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth, this is how I solved the problem (not pretty - but it works):

```
    For Each ControlTableRow In ControlTable.Rows
    
        If ControlTableRow.Row = 1 Then GoTo skip_this
    
        Cat1 = ControlTableRow.Cells(2).Value
        Cat2 = ControlTableRow.Cells(3).Value
        Cat3 = ControlTableRow.Cells(4).Value
        
        'remember previous categories (i.e. hierarchy levels)
        If ControlTableRow.Row = 2 Then
            Cat1_prev = Cat1
            Cat2_prev = Cat2
            Cat3_prev = Cat3
        End If
    
        If Cat1_prev <> "" And Cat1 <> Cat1_prev Then 'Cat1 needs to be summed up
            SumLevel = 1
            write_row_in_target_table '1. totals row
            Cat1_prev = Cat1 'reset
        End If
        
        If Cat2_prev <> "" And Cat2 <> Cat2_prev Then 'Cat2
            SumLevel = 2
            write_row_in_target_table '2. totals row
            Cat2_prev = Cat2
        End If
        
        If Cat3_prev <> "" And Cat3 <> Cat3_prev Then 'Cat3
            SumLevel = 3
            write_row_in_target_table '3. totals row
            Cat3_prev = Cat3
        End If
        
        SumLevel = 0 'I am a leaf row (lowest level)
        write_row_in_target_table
    
    Next ControlTableRow
    
       'Grand Total
    
        Cat1 = "the end"
        Cat2 = "the end"
        Cat3 = "the end"
       
        If Cat1_prev <> "" And Cat1 <> Cat1_prev Then 'Cat1 
            SumLevel = 1
            write_row_in_target_table
            Cat1_prev = Cat1
        End If
      
        If Cat2_prev <> "" And Cat2 <> Cat2_prev Then 'Cat2
            SumLevel = 2
            write_row_in_target_table
            Cat2_prev = Cat2
        End If
        
        If Cat3_prev <> "" And Cat3 <> Cat3_prev Then 'Cat3
            SumLevel = 3
            write_row_in_target_table
            Cat3_prev = Cat3
        End If
```

Based on the value of `SumLevel` the procedure `write_row_in_target_table` writes a totals row that sums and groups the sub nodes/ leaves.

Comment: I made some minor formatting changes to your response